# Check if the elements in list are a multiple of 12

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I am given a list and I am trying to recursively check if the adjacent elements in the list are a multiple of 12, if they are, then I need to check if the remaining sum of the numbers in the list are odd. For example, [6, 6, 5] returns true, [6, 5, 6, 1] returns false. I am having trouble with the case where [10, 7, 5, 5] returns true because (7+5) = 12(multiple of 12) and (10+5) = 15(odd). This is my code. It works when the elements are 0 and 1 index but not when the multiple would be in the middle.

```
public static boolean twoGroups(List<Integer> t) {
    if(t.size()  < 2 ) {
        return false;
    }

    if((t.get(0) * t.get(1)) % 12 == 0){
        List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>(t);
        i.remove(0);
        i.remove(1);
        int works = checkSum(i, 0);
        if(works % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }else { // I think this is where I am going wrong
        List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>(t);
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(i.get(0));
        i.remove(0);
        return twoGroups(i);
    }

}


/*
 * returns true if the sum of the elements of the list is odd
 *Helper method
 */
public static int checkSum(List<Integer> t, int index) {
    if(t.size() == index) {
        return 0;
    }

    return t.get(index) + checkSum(t, index + 1);
}
```

I commented at the part where I think I am going wrong. Plz help

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting what you need. Could you provide some further explanation?

Comment: Hey, that escalates quickly, doesn't it? It might be an idea, to reverse the list, and look for odd remainder sums first, then adjectant multiples of 12, which isn't much less complex, but a bit, a think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have a few issues.

1. In line 6 where you multiply
   `t.get(0) * t.get(1) % 12 == 0`. From the description you gave, you should instead add. [10, 7, 5, 5] would multiply 10 * 7 which equals 70 (a multiple of 12).
2. In lines 8 & 9 `i.remove(0); i.remove(1);` does not remove the variables as you think. First, you remove 10 (index 0) from [10, 7, 5, 5] ->[7, 5, 5]. Then, you remove 5  (the new index 1) [7, 5]
3. You add the variables traversed over into `List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();` but that variable is never used. You should use that list along with the rest of the variables in List t to find the sum.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class Divisible {

    public boolean divisibleBy12(List<Integer> numbers) {
        return divisibleHelper(numbers, 0);
    }

    private boolean divisibleHelper(List<Integer> numbers, int currentIndex) {
        if(numbers.size() <= currentIndex -1) {
            return false;
        } else if(currentIndex + 1 < numbers.size() 
                && isDivisible(numbers.get(currentIndex), numbers.get(currentIndex + 1))) {
            return getSum(numbers, numbers.get(currentIndex), numbers.get(currentIndex + 1));
        } else {
            return divisibleHelper(numbers, currentIndex + 1);
        }
    }

    private boolean getSum(List<Integer> numbers, Integer num1, Integer num2) {
        int sum = numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() - num1 - num2;
        return (sum & 1) == 1;
    }

    private boolean isDivisible(Integer num1, Integer num2) {
        return (num1 + num2) % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Your problem was removing elements from list so you couldn't count them in the sum. Code is a little messy so I'll leave it to you to tidy it up.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a solution in Scala, which is in parts easy to translate in Java, but in parts not so - at least I'm not used to the newly introduced functional parts of Java, I get constantly lost between different collections with their different capabilities.

If we turn the List around, we can first check, if the sublist is odd. Only then, we test the rest of the list incrementally for adding up to a multiple of 12:

```
// easy: sum of list is odd/multiple of 12
def isOdd (l: List[Int]): Boolean = { (l.sum % 2 == 1) }
def dozenix (l: List[Int]): Boolean = { (l.sum % 12 == 0) }
// For (1,8,7,6) test 1 => 1, 8 => 1, 8, 7 => 1, 8, 7, 6
def findDozenic (fromFront: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    (1 to fromFront.size - 1).exists (i => dozenix (fromFront.take (i)))
}
// for (a,b,c,d) test (a)(bcd), (ab)(cd), (abc)(d)
def dozenAfterOddRest (rest: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    for (i <- (1 to rest.length - 1);
    if isOdd (rest.take (i));
    if findDozenic (rest.drop (i))) return true
    return false
}
// initial method to call, turning the list around
def restAfterDozen (rest: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    dozenAfterOddRest (rest.reverse)
}
```

Test:

```
scala> val samples = (1 to 10).map (dummy => (1 to 5).map (foo => {rnd.nextInt (15)+1;}).toList)
samples: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[List[Int]] = Vector(List(13, 3, 14, 8, 2), List(8, 13, 5, 4, 6), List(5, 1, 5, 12, 1), List(5, 14, 15, 8, 2), List(1, 6, 15, 2, 12), List(1, 1, 13, 15, 8), List(4, 15, 2, 10, 8), List(2, 12, 1, 7, 2), List(7, 9, 4, 9, 8), List(6, 8, 7, 15, 8))

scala> samples.map (restAfterDozen)
res107: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Boolean] = Vector(false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)
```

As a true result, List(5, 1, 5, 12, 1) is obviously correct. Last element 1 is odd, in front of it is 12 which is div by 12. I didn't checked the other lists, but changed the code, to make examples better readable:

```
def dozenAfterOddRest (rest: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    for (i <- (1 to rest.length - 1);
    if isOdd (rest.take (i));
    if findDozenic (rest.drop (i))) {
        println (rest.drop (i).reverse.mkString ("+") + "> -- <" + rest.take(i).mkString ("+"));
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

So for

```
Vector(List(1, 3, 3, 8, 2, 7, 3, 7, 5), List(2, 2, 8, 11, 9, 4, 5, 5, 9), List(10, 10, 8, 9, 1, 4, 8, 5, 6), List(3, 10, 2, 6, 3, 2, 10, 4, 2), List(7, 5, 6, 5, 11, 6, 8, 1, 2), List(11, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 6), List(3, 10, 1, 11, 8, 2, 8, 3, 11), List(10, 1, 10, 7, 6, 2, 6, 2, 11), List(10, 9, 10, 9, 3, 8, 9, 5, 4), List(2, 8, 5, 2, 9, 7, 4, 3, 1))
```

it prints (only matches):

```
scala> samples.map (restAfterDozen)
2+2+8+11+9+4> -- <9+5+5   // 9+5+5 is Odd, 4+9=13, +11=24 
10+10+8+9+1+4+8> -- <6+5  // 6+5 odd, 8+4=12
3+10+2> -- <2+4+10+2+3+6  // and so on.
7+5+6+5+11+6+8> -- <2+1
10+1+10+7+6> -- <11+2+6+2
10+9+10+9+3+8+9> -- <4+5
2+8+5+2+9> -- <1+3+4+7
res115: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Boolean] = Vector(false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Java; it works as the scala solution above, and not just for Lists of 4 elements. The code starts with convenience methods, and you have to read it from bottom, where the method is, which is called:

```
int sum (List<Integer> l) {
    return (l.stream().reduce(0, (x,y) -> x+y));
}

boolean isOdd (List<Integer> l) { 
     return (sum(l) % 2 == 1); 
}

boolean dozenix (List<Integer> l) { 
    return (sum(l) % 12 == 0); 
}

// For (1,8,7,6) test 1 => 1, 8 => 1, 8, 7 => 1, 8, 7, 6
boolean findDozenic (List<Integer> fromFront) {
    for (int i = 1; i < fromFront.size() - 1; ++i)
        if (dozenix (fromFront.subList (0, i)))
            return true;
    return false;
}

// for (a,b,c,d) test (a)(bcd), (ab)(cd), (abc)(d)
boolean dozenAfterOddRest (List<Integer> rest) {
    for (int i = 1; i < rest.size () - 1; ++i)
        if (isOdd (rest.subList (0, i)))
            if (findDozenic (rest.subList (i, rest.size () - 1))) 
                return true;
    return false;
}

// initial method to call, turning the list around
boolean restAfterDozen (List<Integer> input) {
    Collections.reverse (input);
    return dozenAfterOddRest (input);
}
```

Since the rest after a sum of dozens has to be odd, I start from the end, searching for an odd sum, because there we are bound to end of the list, while for the parts, which sum up to multiples of 12, they can grow in the end, shrink in the end or shrink at the head. Easy to loose the overview.

From the end it is easy. Last digit odd? Then try to build a divBy12 from the digit in front of it - just a sequential task. If the sum isn't odd, take one next digit and try again, until (former) head of list (now end of list).